# Find out IE proxy settings, even if no access to settings tab because of company policy

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, proxy

What is the easiest way to see if Internet Explorer (on Windows 7) has a proxy configured, IF you don't have access to the LAN settings dialog box because of company policy etc?

I've tried using online tools such as http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check. Although it reports 'no proxy', I think there is one configured, as a python-based program can not connect to google.com. Using IE it connects fine to any website however.

I've also considered wiresharking, but I want to avoid setting it up (need hub, etc.).

Comment: How about asking your company IT staff? Are you sure the Python script isn't faulty?  Can you modify it to attempt to contact Google via IP, or another web site altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a hub or anything special to set up Wireshark.  You can install it on your PC just fine and inspect the traffic on your own NIC.  From there you can inspect the HTTP headers and see if there is a proxy or not.

You could also install Firebug and enable the Net window.  That will also show you the request / response stream.  If the Remote IP column in that windows shows the same IP/Port for all requests then you're behind a proxy or firewall.

Comment: I don't want to (and can't easily) install software on the PC, again because it requires administrator access (which I haven't).